# How to pass a url as string parameter to a form post action

Tags: parameters

So i have a simple form (form.php) that sends some data to another page that saves it to the database (savedata.php).

One of the form fields is a Url field that the user enters a link.

Okay.

When i try to submit a link that has parameters in it, like: http://www.example.com/example.php?id=1&var=1&var=2 then when the form submits it gives error.

Say that the final post action from the form is:

savedata.php?field1=blabla&field2=blabla&urlField=http://www.example.com/example.php?id=1&var=1&var=2

Because the urlField contains a string with "&" it cofuses the post action.
If i submit a url without parameters like: http://www.example.com then its submits the form fine.

One thing that i thought is before submiting the code to replace the "&" with another character like ^ and then on the savedata.php to replace back the "&" sign and then write it to the database.

Is there an easier way to do it?
I already using POST method.

Thanks

Update: OK i see if i replace the "&" sign with "%26" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using post method should fix this problem. Here is an example how to do it:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Change your form method to

```
 method="post">
```

And on the savedata.php read the form by

$url = $_POST['urlField'];

Comment: I'm already using post method and retrieving the parameters with $_POST.

Comment: then why are you passing your parameters to url?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm not passing it by hand. With post it's not visible but under the hood the structure is the same i think.